# upload file and save the path to mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

i have a field form that implement upload file. how can i make upload file and save the path name to database? i need it because i have to make a download link too. Now, i've success to upload file, but it still saved the name of upload file in database not the path of upload file.
and maybe whether if i make a download link to download file that has uploaded?
thanks. i really appreciate.

this is my controller :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('file');
    }

 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('v_upload');
 }

 function do_upload() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|png|gif|jpg|txt|docs|xls';
        $config['max_size'] = '2000';
        $config['max_width']  = '2000';
        $config['max_height']  = '2000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $file1=($_FILES['file1']['name']);
        $file2=($_FILES['file2']['name']);
        $file3=($_FILES['file3']['name']);


        $file = array (
        'rab' => $file1,
        'kkp' => $file2,
        'rcps' => $file3);

        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value) {
            if (!empty($value['tmp_name'])) {

                if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    //failed display the errors
                } else {
                    //upload success
                }

            }
        }
        if ($this->upload->do_upload($key)) {
        $this->file->input_data($file,'upload');
        }
 }
}
```

this is my view :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
<input type="file" name="file1" />
<input type="file" name="file2"/>
<input type="file" name="file3"/>
</div>
<br /><br/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload" />
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
```

this is my model :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class File extends CI_Model{

    function input_data($data,$table){
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try: 
`$file1=($config['upload_path'].$_FILES['file1']['name']);`

for each of the files you upload.

Comment: thx so much. it works @darham and how about make download link to download file that has uploaded?